# Coldfusion case generating an error

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with our Coldfusion application.

The problem is this line I think-:

```
<cfset discountAmountClause = 
"CASE WHEN discountAmount_rateType = 0 THEN #oldPrice# * discountAmount_discount / 100 
ELSE discountAmount_discount END">
```

The error message from the application is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* discountAmount_discount / 100 ELSE discountAmount_discount END

I'm not sure whether there is an issue with the code or something more serious so if anyone with more experience than me can shed some light I would be really grateful...

Comment: `( #oldPrice# * discountAmount_discount ) / 100 ` ?

Comment: Look at the entire SQL statement being sent to the DB. That's a DB error you're citing, not a CF error (you should probably revise your question title, too)

Comment: What is the value of oldPrice?

Comment: Nothing to do with the error per se, but using dynamic sql can expose your database to sql injection. You should strongly consider restructuring your queries to use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html) instead.

Comment: The value of oldprice was the issue! I will post a full answer to explain. @Leigh I am trying to work through all the queries and add paramters but it is a slow process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation and thanks to the help of the comments left in this thread I managed to track down the error to the #oldprice# variable.

One of our pages that called the #oldprice# variable shouldn't have been active because the #oldprice# just didn't exist for that page. A link to this page was included on a number of other pages along with the #oldprice# variable which then caused a bunch of pages to 404 error.

Once I removed the problem page the other pages worked fine and the error stopped being generated.

It was a little harder to track this down as this page was one of 1679! However with the assistance given here I managed to get there in the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `oldPrice` variable has Null or blank value and that is causing your sql to misfire.
You can adjust it conditionally:

```
<cfif oldPrice EQ "">
    <cfset oldPrice = 0>
</cfif>
<cfset discountAmountClause = "CASE WHEN discountAmount_rateType = 0 
                               THEN  #oldPrice# * discountAmount_discount / 100 
                               ELSE discountAmount_discount 
                               END">
```

Comment: Should probably check for `NOT isNumeric(oldPrice)` or perhaps use `val(oldPrice)`

Comment: Agree, but we can't be sure until we know but is coming in oldPrice variable. But as OP is using it in numeric operation, it was just a calculated guess that it has to be numeric value which could be throwing error due to being NULL or BLANK.

Comment: Thankyou @CFML_Developer and Peter (again!). This cfif statement exposed the flaw in the database where the error was occurring. I will post a full answer below. Thanks again.